# awk filter rows based on word range

Tags: awk

I have several files that contain millions of rows where the 6th field is a word (consisting of 3-5 letters).  These words can start with any letter of the alphabet.  I want to filter the output based on the letter the word starts with but the filter needs to go deep into the word, for example I want rows where the word starts with letter A through the letter CRZZZ, then I want rows where the word starts with CS through DMZZZ, etc.

I tried:

```
cat file | awk '$6 ~ /^[A-C]/'| head
```

This code returns rows based on the words' first letter but I need to go deeper into the word, so I tried:

```
cat file |  awk '$6 ~ /^[A-ANZZZ]/'| head
```

But this returns rows where the words starts with A, N or Z.

Comment: Welcome to SO, thanks for sharing your efforts. Could you please do elaborate more on your quote: `I want rows where the word starts with letter A through the letter CRZZZ, then I want rows where the word starts with CS through DMZZZ, etc.` one more in your question, sorry but its not clear, thank you.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to add a [mcve] with concise, testable sample input and expected output that we could test a potential solution against.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you might want this:

```
awk '(("A" <= $6) && ($6 <= "CRZZZ")) || (("CS" <= $6) && ($6 <= "DMZZZ"))' file
```

but without sample input/output it's a guess

Comment: This code passes the simple eye test, I'll test it further, thanks Ed!

Comment: You're welcome but for the benefit of others reading your question now or in future please do add the missing [mcve].